# Magento Customer Lifetime Value

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.7

I need help with mysql query, i want to retrieve our Magento(CE v1.7.0.2) Customer Life Time Value.

which is actually the average total orders by customers from the beginning until now split into months.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try some like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_email, customer_firstname, customer_lastname,
SUM(subtotal_invoiced) AS Total
FROM `sales_flat_order` AS a
GROUP BY customer_email
ORDER BY SUM(subtotal_invoiced) DESC
```

Comment: @FireBear, CLV needs operating margin from a user, the discount rate, the retention rate of customers, and the acquisition cost. None of those are in your query. You're answering some different question.